# Laravel user, role, permission relationship implemention problem

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, relationship, laravel-relations

I have three Models `User`, `Role` and `Permission`. There is complicated but well-known relation between these Models and their tables.

Tables and their columns :

| users | roles | permissions | permission_role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id | id |
| ... | ... | ... | role_id |
| role_id | ... | ... | permission_id |

So **each User has only one role and every role has many permissions**.

```
<?php

class User
{


public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    
}

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Permission::class,Role::class);
}
}


class Role
{


public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
  
}

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    
}
}


class Permission
{


public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class,Role::class);
}
}
```

I can access

1. $user->role,
2. $user->role->permissions,
3. $role->users,
4. $role->permissions
5. $permission->roles

**except** for

1. **$permission->users**

which returns sql error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.permission_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `roles`.`permission_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `users` inner join `roles` on `roles`.`id` = `users`.`role_id` where `roles`.`permission_id` = 1)
```

But why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

###### Permission

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        User::class,    // The model to access to
        PermissionRole::class,    // The intermediate table that connects the User with the Role.
        'permission_id',   // The column of the intermediate table that connects to this model by its ID.
        'role_id',    // The column of the intermediate table that connects the Role by its ID.
        'id',    // The column that connects this model with the intermediate model table.
        'role_id'   // The column of the Users table that ties it to the Roles. 
    );
}
```

I found [this](https://darkghosthunter.medium.com/laravel-has-many-through-pivot-elegantly-958dd096db) article.

And if you compare with your tables it can be like:

- `audio_files` table is your `users`
- `podcast` table is your `roles`
- `subscription` table is your `permission_role`
- `users` table is your `permissions`

Maybe it's confusing, but please let me know if this works.